# Infimum and limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

I was having trouble with the following question. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Let $A$ be the set of K-dimensional vectors with non-negative components. Let $B$ be the set of K-dimensional vectors with positive components.

Let $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Let $c\in\mathbb{R}$ be any number and let $C=\{a\in\ A | f(a)\geq c\}$.

Let $b_n$ be a sequence in $B$ that converges to another element $b\in B$ w.r.t. the Euclidean norm.

Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \inf_{a\in C} ab_n = \inf_{a\in C} ab$, where multiplication is the dot product of vectors. Also, $C$ is given as non-empty, and clearly by the construction of $A$ and $B$ the infimum will never be $-\infty$.

I can only show one direction.

Comment: Wnat do you mean by $ab_n$ and $ab$? Is that supposed to be a dot product? Where do $f$ and $C$ fit into this problem?

Comment: Instead of "K-dimensional vectors" I'd prefer "elements of $\mathbb R^K$" (for several reasons). And do you mean $\inf_{a\in C, n\in\mathbb N} ab_n=\inf_{a\in C} ab$? That would surely be wrong. Or possibly $\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf_{a\in C} ab_n=\inf_{a\in C} ab$?

Comment: Thanks Hagen, hopefully fixed for the last time now. It is basically being able to switch limit with infimum, which happens when function converges uniformly. That wont be the case here though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof sketch.

1. First of all, for every $x\in B$ there exist $y\in C$ such that $x\cdot y = \inf_{c\in C} x\cdot c$. Indeed let $\alpha = \min_{c\in C} x\cdot c$. Let $R= \{z:z_i \leq \alpha / x_i\}$. Then 
   $$\inf_{c\in C} x\cdot c = \inf_{c\in C\cap R} x\cdot c.$$
   But $C$ is a closed set, $R$ is a closed and bounded set, therefore, $C\cap R$ is a compact set. Thus there exist $y\in C\cap R$ that minimizes $x\cdot y$.
2. Let $a^*\in B$ be the value of $a$ that minimizes $a\cdot b$; let $a_n^*\in B$ be the value of $a$ that minimizes $a\cdot b_n$.
3. We need to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty}  a_n^*\cdot b_n = a^*\cdot b$. Note that $a_n^*\cdot b_n \leq a^* \cdot b_n$ for every $n$ and thus $\lim\sup_{n\to \infty}  a_n^*\cdot b_n \leq \lim_{n\to \infty}  a^*\cdot b_n =a^*\cdot b$. Now we prove that $\lim\inf_{n\to \infty}  a_n^*\cdot b_n \geq a^*\cdot b$. Let $k_n$ be a subsequence s.t. $a_{k_n}^*\cdot b_{k_n} \to \lim\inf_{n\to \infty}  a_n^*\cdot b_n$. Note that $a_n$ is a bounded sequence, and hence $a^*_{k_n}$ is also bounded. Let $a'$ be a limit point of $a_{k_n}^*$. Then 
   $$\lim\inf_{n\to \infty}  a_n^*\cdot b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{k_n}^*\cdot b_{k_n} = a'\cdot b \geq a^*\cdot b.$$